# how to using axios in redux action when working with nextJS?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, next.js

I'm using NextJS, I want to fetch data with axios in redux action, but my code not working. i have no idea whats wrong with my code. here is my code

// action

```
function fetchImg() {
  return async dispatch => {
    return await axios.get(`${wpAPIEndpoint}/posts/1629`).then(response => {
      dispatch({
        type: 'FETCH_IMG',
        payload: response.data
      });
    });
  };
}
```

// here is my function in App.js

```
 static getInitialProps({ store, isServer }) {
    store.dispatch(fetchImg());
 }
```

// store

```
const configureStore = (initialState = {}) => {
  const middlewares = [thunk, promise];
  return createStore(
    reducers,
    initialState,
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middlewares))
  );
};
```

Comment: In what way is the code not working? Is it failing with an error? Have you tried adding `console.log`s to see what is running and what isn't?